# Calculating powers of big numbers

Tags: c++, long-integer

I am writing a program in C++ where I have to calculate the value of n^n where 1<=n<=10^9. But even if I use `long long` type to store the result, the answer is calculated just till n=15.
At n=16, a floating point exception arises and and after that results show negative values. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the code?

```
long long c;

c=(long long)n;
for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
   c*=n;

 cout<<c<<endl;
```

Comment: (10^9)^(10^9). Universe overflow exception..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting negative values then you are overflowing the variable. You need to use a data type that has a larger range, one that is sufficient to hold the numbers you wish to calculate. If your system does not come with such a data type (and I rather suspect that `long long` is as big as you will get) then you will need to use a bignum class.

Looking more closely at the numbers in your question, I think that many standard bignum classes will not be able to calculate n<sup>n</sup> for n=10<sup>9</sup>. Are you sure you wrote the problem down correctly?

Comment: n^n for 10^9 is a REALLY huge number. Even a big integer type can not hold it unless you have a LOT of RAM.

Comment: @istrandjev Yeah, I just got round to thinking about that. I'd guess Anant transcribed the problem incorrectly.

Comment: ..so much so that, if God transformed all the atoms in the observable universe into RAM chips, it would be nowhere near enough.

Comment: Nope - it is not THAT much. Only about 9*10^9 digits.

Comment: (10^9)^(10^9)=10^(9*10^9) which is 9 billion decimal digits long. This would required around 3.75GB of memory to represent in binary notation. Printing the answer would require around two million pieces of paper.

Comment: I agree and I have pointed out that the number is big in my answer. However I don't want to live in a universe with less then 10^10 atoms as this would feel a bit too cosy.

Comment: Wikipeadia estimate of no. of atoms in the obervable universe = 10^80.  This is quite a bit less than 10^(10^9).  (10^9)^(10^9) is even bigger, but who cares aboout an extra 9 zeros??

Comment: @RaymondChen - the exponent is 9 billion decimal digits long.  The OP wants an integer answer.  This is where Deep Thought went wrong - the remainder after the universe-overflow was 42.

Comment: @MartinJames The exponent is only 10 digits long. (a^b)^c = a^(bc). Take a=10, b=9, c=10^9.

Comment: In OP post there is no 'a', 'b', 'c', just 'n'.

Comment: @Martin If you can't see that Raymond's formula equals n^n where n=10^9 then you should back out of this conversation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be missing something.  Raising any number much above 1 to such an enormous power will surely be, well, enormous?  If 10^80 is 'universe size', what is 10^(10^9)?  80<<<10^9.  I'm not being deliberately pedantic or awkward - I just don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

`long long` type has 64 bits and is signed. This means that the largest number you can store in it is 2<sup>63</sup> - 1. The number you're trying to calculate is 16<sup>16</sup> which is (2<sup>4</sup>)<sup>16</sup>=2<sup>64</sup> and hence does not fit in `long long`.

Try using floating point type `double`, but the result will not be exact.

Comment: `long long` doesn't always have 64 bits, but clearly it does on this particular platform.

Comment: True, C99 requires it to have _at least_ 64 bits, but yeah, here it definitely is 64.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have given a link to the actual problem(btw the link given does not open properly because it has a ']' in the end so for anyone interested [here](http://www.codechef.com/problems/MARCHA4) is a working link) I can propose a solution for it.

You do not need to compute the number itself all you need to do is compute some properties of it. For the last k digits all you have to do is compute the remainder of n^n when divided by 10^k. This can be done using [fast exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) in logarithmic time. For the first k - digits  where k is less then 10 my approach would be the following - do something like the fast exponentiation but only care about the first m digits of each intermediate result. I think that m=100 should be sufficient to give you the correct answer if not experiment with higher values of m. The complexity of this calculation would be logarithmic times m.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You get negative values because 16^16 = 2^64  and the range for long long is up to 2^63 - 1. So you overflow the long long type. There is no built-in type that can cope with the kind of calcluation you want to do and even more: for 10^9 the value of n^n has 9*10^9 digits and will hardly fit into the memory of a regular computer. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to solve a problem given here:[http://www.codechef.com/problems/MARCHA4]

Comment: I have added another answer on how to approach that problem. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Do the calculation logarithmic for higher numbers.

```
log(n^n) = n * log(n)
```

If you do this in base 10, you can print the result algorithmically on the screen:

```
auto res = log10(n) * n;
auto integer_part = floor(res);
auto fractional_part = res - integer_part;

auto mantissa = pow(10, fractional_part);
```

Now `mantissa` holds the digits of your result and `integer_part` holds how many times you have to shift the comma to the right.